# How to disable links for touch devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am planning to use some kind of tooltip function. On desktop, I would like it to open with hover effect and also have a link and direct whenever user clicks. On touch devices, I would like to disable link and open tooltip only by touching(clicking whatever). So basically, I need to disable links for touch devices. It would be very useful to assign a CSS class for that.

Thanks for your help.
Cheers.

Comment: Could you use :hover because touch devices don't support it while non-mobile does?

Comment: In the future, it's best to say what you've tried already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript:

```
if ('ontouchstart' in window) {
    $("a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // trigger tooltip...
    });
}
```

Change the selector to something more restrictive if you don't want all `<a>`s to be targeted.

---

Also, it's better to use Modernizr for these things. If you're OK with including another library, it will do a good job. Here's a link to a custom build that only tests for touch event: http://modernizr.com/download/#-touch-teststyles-prefixes

And then replace the condition of the IF with `Modernizr.touch`.

Answer (score 1):

I've used a JS approach where I set a `data-*` attribute on the first touch event and used `event.preventDefault()` to cancel the link action. If a second touch event was fired (i.e. the user touched a second time) I could now check if the `data-*` attribute was set and do nothing – that means the event handler returned `true` and the link action was performed. This is very common when dealing with flyout-menus, where the first level items also link to some sort of subpage.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to detect touch screens in JS is to use the `MatchMedia` API.

```js
// target touchscreens of any viewport width
if(window.matchMedia("(hover: none) and (pointer: coarse)").matches) {
// target touchscreens of a specific width
// if(window.matchMedia("(hover: none) and (pointer: coarse) and (min-width: 1024px)").matches) {

  var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");

  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {

    var link = links[i];

    link.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }, false);

  }

}

// This obviously targets all links, so you'll need to be more specific than this.
```